# Symfony ManyToMany setter return wrong data

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, many-to-many

I have relation User to Coupon ManyToMany.
User have many coupons and coupon may belong to many users.
When I call the method $coupon->getUsers(), I get coupon (PersistentCollection).
And when I call the method $user->getCoupon(), I get user (PersistentCollection).

**User entity:**

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Coupon", inversedBy="users")
     */
    private $coupon;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->coupon = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Coupon[]
     */
    public function getCoupon(): Collection
    {
        return $this->coupon;
    }

    public function addCoupon(Coupon $coupon): self
    {
        if (!$this->coupon->contains($coupon)) {
            $this->coupon[] = $coupon;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeCoupon(Coupon $coupon): self
    {
        if ($this->coupon->contains($coupon)) {
            $this->coupon->removeElement($coupon);
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

**Coupon entity:**

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", mappedBy="coupon")
     */
    private $users;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|User[]
     */
    public function getUsers(): Collection
    {
        return $this->users;
    }

    public function addUser(User $user): self
    {
        if (!$this->users->contains($user)) {
            $this->users[] = $user;
            $user->addCoupon($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeUser(User $user): self
    {
        if ($this->users->contains($user)) {
            $this->users->removeElement($user);
            $user->removeCoupon($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

**When I run this code:**

```
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Coupon;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class TestController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/test", name="test")
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $coupon = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Coupon::class)->find(1);

        dump($coupon->getUsers());die;
    }
}
```

I get:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XX6WV.png)

Why I get a coupon and not a list of users?

Comment: are you sure the coupon with id 1 is related to some user in your database ?

Answer (score 1):

On top of what Jakumi wrote, in the controller you can also do

```php
$coupon = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Coupon::class)->find(1);

$users = $coupon->getUsers();
$users->initialize();
```

Now when you `dump($users)` the collection should not be empty.

To add to that, I believe you have your mapping wrong. In your Many-To-Many relation the `User` is the owning side and `Coupon` is the inversed side, however it is the `public function addUser(User $user)` in the `Coupon` entity that does the [owning side's job](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#owning-and-inverse-side-on-a-manytomany-association). You should either change the sides (change the `mappedBy` in `Coupon` to `inversedBy` and the other way around in the `User`) or make sure that `User` does:

```php
public function addCoupon(Coupon $coupon): self
{
    if (!$this->coupon->contains($coupon)) {
        $coupon->addUser($this);
        $this->coupon[] = $coupon;
    }

    return $this;
}
```

and the `Coupon` does:

```php
public function addUser(User $user): self
{
    if (!$this->users->contains($user)) {
        $this->users[] = $user;
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Of course the `removeUser` and `removeCoupon` methods should be dealth with accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

`PersistentCollection`s conceptually are supposed to work like arrays and are the way of doctrine to realize lazy loading (the default). There are certain operations that will trigger the collection to be loaded from the database (such as iterating over the collection). Before that, it's property `initialized` will be false (as in your screenshot)

ManyToMany and OneToMany should always be realized as ArrayCollection (or some other collection, such as PersistentCollection) and should not be leaked to the outside. Instead call `->toArray()` (or `->asArray()`, I always forget) to return them (so, inside `getUsers()` or `getCoupons()` respectively). Inside the entity you can just `foreach` over the `PersistentCollection`.

If you mark the ManyToMany to `fetch` as `EAGER`, it will be loaded immediately, but that might have performance impact...

And the Collection holds a reference to the object it belongs to, so you're not getting a Coupon per se, you get a collection, that still references its owner ;o)